# Google App Engine - Java-backend and Angular-frontend in a single project

Tags: java, angular, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform

I am building a **Angular 2 web app** which uses a **Java GAE / Cloud Endpoints API as backend**. My aims are to

1. run both in a single Google Cloud Platform project `my-project`
2. edit both parts in a single project folder using e.g. IntelliJ IDEA, without having to switch between two IDEs/projects.

My status quo is as follows:

Currently, I have an Java App Engine project folder containing my API. This is currently deployed on `my-project`. I use IntelliJ IDEA to edit it. Basic structure of my backend project folder:

```
Backend
    .idea
    src/main
            java //My entire code is here
            webapp
                index.html //Just a stub
                WEB-INF
                        appengine-web.xml
                        web.xml
                        logging.properties
    build.gradle
    pom.xml
    <Some other files>
```

Furthermore, I have an Angular 2 project folder with my frontend seperately. Until now, I have only tested this web app locally and have never deployed it. I have used WebStorm to edit it. Basic folder structure:

```
Frontend
    e2e
    node_modules
    src
        app
        assets
        environments
        index.html
        stlyes.css
        <Some other files>
    angular.cli.json
    package.json
    <Some other files>
```

**Now, how can I merge these two parts into one project to achieve what I have stated above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is yes. The client and server code can be developed using IntelliJ Ultimate edition in the same project folder.

In my GAE project I'm using Python rather than Java, but the setup for Java could be nearly identical.

## My Project Structure

```
+-- .idea
|
+-- dist
|
+-- node_modules
|
+-- src
   |
   +-- app
   |  |
   |  +-- app.module.ts
   |
   +-- server
   |  |
   |  +-- <Python code>  // Or your Java code
   |
   +-- tools
   |
   \-- index.html
```

I use [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to build the project, with all of the client Javascript bundles placed directly under `dist` as well as `app.yaml`. Most of my server code is run under a "backend" service, which is placed under `dist/backend`. This is just personal preference.

The app is deployed with the command:

```
cd dist_prod && gcloud app deploy -v v1 --project api-project-######## --verbosity debug
```

Comment: Why do you explicitly say "Ultimate Edition"? Doesn't it work with the Commnity Edition?

Comment: @nkxandroid, IntelliJ Community edition doesn't support Javascript, Typescript, or CSS. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html